# Search function on action bar for list view

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I need help in order to achieve my **search function on action bar**. IThis tutorial shown how to do list view using simple list item, while my code, I used custom Adapter class.

Comment: wich one is line 78?

Comment: searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your searchView is null. Instead of this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Use this:

```
inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.item_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

And take a look to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget).

**EDIT**

I copy your code and I tested. I found an error. I don't know if is another error or is the same error that you are having.

When you declare ListView variable, you are setting to global scope but when you give it a value (R.id.listView value) you are declaring another ListView variable with method scope.

Don't do this `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Do this `listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);`

Making that change, this line: `listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);` will not give you NullPointerException.

I hope that fix your code. In other case, you should put your logcat output in your question for further details. And in your future questions too ;).

Comment: I already changed but my apps still stop. Its still give me error on ths line  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

Comment: And how looks your menu.xml file?

Comment: Hi jorge. I already try. When i change custom adapter to adapter its give error.

Comment: @Let you dont need to change adapter, just change listView line

Comment: no more error @jorge bu when i run the apps crash and give me this line :

Comment: searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                     at com.example.myuser.customlistview.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:88)

Comment: In menu.xml you have `app:actionViewClass="android:.support.v7.widget.Searchview"`. Delete two dots ":" and Serchview to SearchView `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: You have to make that item from menu.xml resources be the same class that you are importing in your MainActivity.java `import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`

Comment: You have to make that item from menu.xml resources be the same class that you are importing in your MainActivity.java import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView --- > what do you mean by this?

Comment: The class in app:actionViewClass must be the same class that you import and use in the MainActivity, the SearchView class. Thats why searchView object, wich is a instance of SearchView class, is giving you NullPointerException, because there isn't item in menu.xml with that class since you are writing wrong.

Comment: the apps and search button appeared, when I try to search the apps stop.

Comment: So the problem with the SearchView is solve!! Dont forget to mark this answer as correct ;) Your new problem is because of the ArrayAdapter instantiation. You should write `new ArrayAdapter<>          (MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_black_text, R.id.textView2, templist);` You can easily find more info in [google](https://www.google.es/search?q=ArrayAdapter+requires+the+resource+id+to+be+a+textview&oq=ArrayAdapter+requires+the+resource+id+to+be+a+textview) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23020408/java-lang-illegalstateexception-arrayadapter-requires-the-resource-id-to-be-a-t)

Comment: Its working no more error. But actually i want it search both two lines of text.Now its only show the uppercase part. the lowecase part only appear as textview when we search

Comment: When i do searching its only textVIew2 appear but not textView3. Bcs textView2 and 3 is the same things. only small and capital letter. When i close search button then the textView3 no longer display.

Comment: Thats because in onCreate you set the adapter for the listview as a customadapter, but in searchview.onquerytextlistener you set the adapter for the listview as a normal arrayadapter.

Comment: how can i set in searchview.onquerytextlistener as customadapter? because i need smth like tht.so it can both appear at textView2 and 3 when I run its ;)

Comment: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: Do you mean i need to define class for textview 2 and textview 3 on main activity? and do i need to create new xml file for view template or just using list_black_item?

Comment: You should use your custom adapter to assign values to list_black_item.xml in the same way the tutorial use UserAdapter to assing values to item_user.xml

Comment: These are very basic questions and you should ask in another post. I solve your question for searchview and the problem was you are not typing exactly what is in the youtube video. Now you have another problem implementing a custom adapter for your listview and i give you a good tutorial. Just follow that tutorial and learn from it and if you dont understand something ask in another post

Answer (score 1):

instead of this code on getVeiw method :

```
view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_black_text, null);
```

use this one

```
 if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_black_text, null);
    }
```

maybe this work for you

Comment: context.getSystemService and convertView give me error

Comment: because you are in mainActivity you don't need context
see it again i update that

Comment: i fixed it for you 
lock at the answer again.

Comment: no more error but my apps still stop when I run its. When I click debug its show me this line error :  searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()

Answer (score 0):

> This line of code give you null pointer exception because it does not
>   exist in your current layout. Check your xml File man!

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){
```

> And look through your code there is a missing ; after search view
>   declaration

SearchView searchView = (SearchView)

Comment: Its not missing, that sentence continue on the next line.